# How to get related set in django(Many to many field)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have an Employee model

```
class Employees(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter the name of the employee")
location = models.ManyToManyField('Coverage')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name'
```

And a Location model

```
class Coverage(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=300, help_text="Enter employee location")
time_needed = models.IntegerField(help_text="Enter time needed to get to work. eg (40 = > 40 minutes)")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

How do i access coverage  - time_needed from my templates with (         employees = Employees.objects.all())

I have tried `{{employees.location.time_needed}}` but it doesn't work. Any good answer would be appreciated.

ps : this is just a snippet of a bigger model class

Comment: I don't see any link between the 2 models. `location = models.ManyToManyField('Location')` where's the `Location` model?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I would update the models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`employees = Employees.objects.all()` is a queryset, you can't access fields with it. But instead if you iterate through it, you will have access to each instance, then you will be able to have `location` for any instance. Since `location` is a ManyToManyField `location = models.ManyToManyField('Location')`. you will need to iterate through it as well.

```
{% for employee in employees %}
    {{ employee.location.all }} // Location queryset

    {% for location in employee.location.all %}
          {{ location.time_needed }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't really need to iterate through these fields. You can use `slice` to select an instance

`{{ employees.0 }}` will select the first employee instance depending on your queryset ordering

`{{ employee.0.location.all.0 }}` select the first location instance depending on your queryset ordering

`{{ employee.0.location.all.0.time_needed }}` will give you access to the value.

Or much clearer:

```
{% with employees.0 as employee %}
     {% with location as employee.location.all.0 %}
         {{ location.time_needed }}
     {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can do something like this :

```
employees = Employees.objects.all()
for employee in employees:
   for location in employee.location.all():
      print(location.time_needed)
```

if you want to access a particular Coverage, then you can do something like this :

```
Coverage.objects.filter(id__in=employee.location.all().values('id')).values('time_needed')
# This will return time_needed of all the Coverage whose id matched the location ids of employee
```